How to add private instance package as a dependency to other private instance package
I'm trying to use created package as a dependecy in my other package.
I'm working on private instace of gitlab.
So to install the first package I would use command like this:
pip install <package> --index-url https://__token__:<your_personal_token>@<instace_url>/api/v4/projects/1064/packages/pypi/simple 
But the point is I want to use it as dependency (in toml file) of another package which would be installed exaclty same way, that is:
pip install <main_package> --index-url https://__token__:<your_personal_token>@<instace_url>/api/v4/projects/1050/packages/pypi/simple
So I build a .toml file to include all depedencies but putting it like this:
<package> @ <instance_url>/api/v4/projects/1064/packages/pypi/simple
Does not cut it.  ERROR: HTTP error 404
How can I include the package in depedency list?
Edit.
Adding .toml file
`
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

dependencies = [
    "<package> @ <instace_url>/api/v4/projects/1064/packages/pypi/simple",
    "spacy==3.7.5",
    "opencv-python==4.10.0.84",
    "numpy==1.26.4",
    "cryptography==43.0.1",
    "pillow==10.3.0",
    "scipy==1.11.1",
    "easyocr==1.7.1",
    "matplotlib==3.6.0",
    "requests==2.32.3",
    "unidecode==1.3.8",
    "pandas==2.2.3",
    "transformers==4.46.3",
    "scikit-learn==1.5.2"
]

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"<main_package>.config" = ["*.json"]

`

Add a minimum snippet of the relevant toml section please

Add -vvv to pip command and check the log. For credentials, look at creating a pypirc file to store them to not save them on pyproject.toml
